# Help identifying my juniper bonsair?

Tags: identification, trees, bonsai

I went to a nursery earlier today and got a bonsai tree. I've always wanted a bonsai tree however never had gotten around to it. Looking at photos makes me think it's a Green Mound Juniper however I was hoping I could get some confirmation.

[image: Juniper]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a procumbens juniper. 'Green Mound is one of several varieties of this species, but the primary one. Of late, it seems that 'nana' will be the cultivar name.

I think your i.d. is spot on. It's growth habits make it ideal for cascade and semi-cascade bonsai styles.